# Problems with Mysqldump command

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, vps

I have a Debian VPS with mysql installed and i want to export a database.

After have successful login in to mysql.

I run the follow command:

```
mysqldump -u user -p mydatabase > db.sql
```

but I got the following error:

```
->
```

It doesn't export the database and I can´t type anything.

Comment: Mysql expects a command to be terminated by a semicolon.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: command line command followed by `;`?

Comment: @Johan: does it request you for a password?

Comment: as in select * from sometable; at the mysql prompt, which is why the op was just getting an other prompt...

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson: what is the reason to put `;` after the command to run in `mysql` prompt if the command should be run in a shell?

Comment: If the command should be run in shell, none. However with the semicolon in Mysql, would have then got an error about mysqldump wouldn't they...

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to login to mysql. Just type:

```
mysqldump -u user -p mydatabase > db.sql
```

on the command line, meaning the shell. It will ask you for a password and then writes the dump to db.sql

Comment: Thanks!

it helped me out!